# transform coding in nodejs with Iconv

Tags: node.js, utf-8, iso-8859-1, iconv

I am trying to transform the encoding a text, to get the original text. But it only returns the correct text from a variable created by me, not by a variable of another function.
A major, when I try to transform another text (Hakaba Kitarō) I get error:
`(node:5436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal character sequence.`

```
function iso_to_utf8 (text) {
    console.log(`text orginal: ${text}`); //return text orginal: "Queen\u00c2\u0092s Blade OVA 2011"
    body = new Buffer.from(text, "utf8");
    conv = new Iconv("utf8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "ISO-8859-1");
    body = conv.convert(body).toString();
    console.log(body); //return Queen\u00c2\u0092s Blade OVA 2011
    body = new Buffer.from("Queen\u00c2\u0092s Blade OVA 2011", "utf8");
    conv = new Iconv("utf8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "ISO-8859-1");
    body = conv.convert(body).toString();
    console.log(body); //return Queens Blade OVA 2011

    return body;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the \u00c2\u0092 character sequence? That's the byte sequence \xc3\x82\xc2\x92 when converted to UTF-8.

//TRANSLIT correctly copies that to the output buffer as the ISO-8859-1 byte sequence \xc2\x92, which .toString() then interprets as UTF-8 and converts to U+0092, a control character that your terminal may or may not display.

(All characters in the range U+007F-U+009F are control characters, by the way.)

That's all expected behavior and working as intended so I'm going to go ahead and close this out.
By bnoordhuis